# When is a HTTP response code actually 200 OK?

Tags: httpresponse

In creating an API (and other things), many client-side examples look like this:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }

    };

    ...
```

So that got me thinking, what is actually OK?

Specifically, if the request produces a programmed error for something like bad data, the request has technically worked so is this "OK"? And then, what should the severity of the error be to return a 400 - bad login?

Comment: you should look into error codes, anything in 200 is success, 201 is created, 203 no content, anything 400s is request error (something client is passing is bad), and 500 is server errors. 200 means it was successful and there are results returned. 200 won't be passed if there is an error